TypeError: Dispatcher.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given Помогите
import logging
import sqlite3
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
from aiogram.filters import Command
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random

# Включаем логирование
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Укажи здесь свой токен бота
API_TOKEN = 'Token'

# Список разрешённых ID пользователей
ALLOWED_USERS = {3423423423}  # Ваш ID добавлен сюда

# Инициализация бота и диспетчера
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)  # Передаем бот в диспетчер

# Создаем кнопки
button_menu = KeyboardButton(text='Меню')
button_profile = KeyboardButton(text='Мой профиль')
button_back = KeyboardButton(text='Назад')
button1 = KeyboardButton(text='Снос аккаунта')
button2 = KeyboardButton(text='Снос канала')
button3 = KeyboardButton(text='Снос бота')
button_subscriptions = KeyboardButton(text='Подписки')

# Новые кнопки для управления подписками
button_give_access = KeyboardButton(text='Выдать подписку')
button_remove_access = KeyboardButton(text='Удалить подписку')
button_extend_access = KeyboardButton(text='Продлить подписку')  # Новая кнопка

# Функция, возвращающая клавиатуру для профиля
def get_profile_keyboard(user_id: int) -> ReplyKeyboardMarkup:
    if user_id in ALLOWED_USERS:
        return ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
            [button_menu],
            [button_profile, button_subscriptions]
        ], resize_keyboard=True)
    else:
        return ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
            [button_menu],
            [button_profile]
        ], resize_keyboard=True)

# Функция создания клавиатуры для меню
action_keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
    [button1],
    [button2],
    [button3],
    [button_back]
], resize_keyboard=True)

# Функция создания клавиатуры для подписок
subscriptions_keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
    [button_give_access],
    [button_remove_access],
    [button_extend_access],  # Добавленная кнопка
    [button_back]
], resize_keyboard=True)

# Функция инициализации базы данных
def init_db():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('tempusers.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_access (
            user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            expiration_time TEXT
        )
    ''')
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

# Функция добавления подписки
def add_subscription(user_id: int, expiration_time: datetime):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('tempusers.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
        INSERT OR REPLACE INTO temp_access (user_id, expiration_time)
        VALUES (?, ?)
    ''', (user_id, expiration_time.isoformat()))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

# Функция удаления подписки
def remove_subscription(user_id: int):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('tempusers.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('DELETE FROM temp_access WHERE user_id = ?', (user_id,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

# Функция получения времени окончания подписки
def get_subscription(user_id: int) -> datetime:
    conn = sqlite3.connect('tempusers.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT expiration_time FROM temp_access WHERE user_id = ?', (user_id,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.close()
    if result:
        return datetime.fromisoformat(result[0])
    return None

# Функция проверки, разрешён ли пользователь
def is_user_allowed(user_id: int) -> bool:
    if user_id in ALLOWED_USERS:
        return True
    expiration_time = get_subscription(user_id)
    if expiration_time and expiration_time > datetime.now():
        return True
    return False

# Функция форматирования оставшегося времени
def format_remaining_time(expiration_time: datetime) -> str:
    now = datetime.now()
    remaining_time = expiration_time - now

    if remaining_time.total_seconds() <= 0:
        return "Подписка истекла"

    days, remainder = divmod(remaining_time.total_seconds(), 86400)  # 86400 секунд в дне
    hours, remainder = divmod(remainder, 3600)  # 3600 секунд в часе
    minutes, _ = divmod(remainder, 60)  # 60 секунд в минуте

    return f"{int(days)} дн. {int(hours)} ч. {int(minutes)} мин."

# Функция форматирования даты в буквенном виде
def format_date(date: datetime) -> str:
    months = ["Января", "Февраля", "Марта", "Апреля", "Мая", "Июня", "Июля", "Августа", "Сентября", "Октября", "Ноября", "Декабря"]
    month = months[date.month - 1]
    return f"{date.day} {month} {date.year} года, {date.strftime('%H:%M:%S')}"

# Функция получения юзернейма пользователя
async def get_username(user_id: int) -> str:
    try:
        chat_member = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=user_id, user_id=user_id)
        return chat_member.user.username or "Не указан"
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Не удалось получить информацию о пользователе {user_id}: {e}")
        return "Не указан"

# Функция форматирования подписок в виде строки
async def format_subscriptions() -> str:
    conn = sqlite3.connect('tempusers.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT user_id, expiration_time FROM temp_access')
    subscriptions = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()

    if not subscriptions:
        return "Нет активных подписок."

    result = f"Активные подписки ({len(subscriptions)}):\n"
    for index, (user_id, expiration_time) in enumerate(subscriptions, start=1):
        username = await get_username(user_id)
        result += f"{index}. Юзернейм: @{username} , ID пользователя: {user_id} , До: {format_date(datetime.fromisoformat(expiration_time))}\n"

    return result

# Обработчик команды /start
@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    if is_user_allowed(message.from_user.id):
        await message.answer("Привет! Нажмите 'Меню', чтобы открыть основные действия.", reply_markup=get_profile_keyboard(message.from_user.id))
    else:
        await message.answer("Извините, у вас нет доступа к этому боту. Вы можете открыть 'Мой профиль'.")

# Обработчик кнопки "Меню"
@dp.message(lambda message: message.text == "Меню")
async def show_main_menu(message: types.Message):
    if is_user_allowed(message.from_user.id):
        await message.answer("Выберите действие:", reply_markup=action_keyboard)
    else:
        await message.answer("Извините, у вас нет доступа к этому разделу.")

# Обработчик кнопки "Назад"
@dp.message(lambda message: message.text == "Назад")
async def go_back(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == "Назад" and message.reply_markup == subscriptions_keyboard:
        await message.answer("Вы вернулись в меню подписок.", reply_markup=get_profile_keyboard(message.from_user.id))
    else:
        await message.answer("Вы вернулись в главное меню.", reply_markup=get_profile_keyboard(message.from_user.id))

# Обработчик кнопки "Мой профиль"
@dp.message(lambda message: message.text == "Мой профиль")
async def show_profile(message: types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    username = message.from_user.username or "Не указан"
    first_name = message.from_user.first_name or "Не указан"  # Добавляем имя пользователя
    expiration_time = get_subscription(user_id)
    subscription_status = "Не активна"

    if expiration_time:
        subscription_status = format_remaining_time(expiration_time)

    profile_info = (
        f"Ваш профиль:\n"
        f"Имя: {first_name}\n"
        f"Юзернейм: @{username}\n"
        f"ID: {user_id}\n"
        f"Подписка: {subscription_status}"
    )
    await message.answer(profile_info, reply_markup=get_profile_keyboard(user_id))

# Обработчик кнопки "Подписки"
@dp.message(lambda message: message.text == "Подписки")
async def show_subscriptions(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id in ALLOWED_USERS:
        subscriptions_info = await format_subscriptions()
        await message.answer(subscriptions_info, reply_markup=subscriptions_keyboard)
    else:
        await message.answer("Извините, у вас нет доступа к этому разделу.")

# Обработчик кнопки "Выдать подписку"
@dp.message(lambda message: message.text == "Выдать подписку")
async def give_access(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id in ALLOWED_USERS:
        await message.answer("Отправьте ID пользователя и время подписки в днях в формате:\n<ID пользователя> <Время в днях>")
    else:
        await message.answer("Извините, у вас нет доступа к этому действию.")

# Обработчик кнопки "Удалить подписку"
@dp.message(lambda message: message.text == "Удалить подписку")
async def remove_access(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id in ALLOWED_USERS:
        await message.answer("Отправьте ID пользователя для удаления подписки.")
    else:
        await message.answer("Извините, у вас нет доступа к этому действию.")

# Обработчик кнопки "Продлить подписку"
@dp.message(lambda message: message.text == "Продлить подписку")
async def extend_access(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id in ALLOWED_USERS:
        await message.answer("Отправьте ID пользователя для продления подписки и время в днях в формате:\n<ID пользователя> <Время в днях>")
    else:
        await message.answer("Извините, у вас нет доступа к этому действию.")

# Обработчик кнопки "Снос аккаунта", "Снос канала" и "Снос бота"
@dp.message(lambda message: message.text in ["Снос аккаунта", "Снос канала", "Снос бота"])
async def start_deletion_process(message: types.Message):
    if is_user_allowed(message.from_user.id):
        await message.answer("Отправьте юзернейм для удаления.")
    else:
        await message.answer("Извините, у вас нет доступа к этому действию.")

# Обработчик получения юзернейма для удаления
@dp.message(lambda message: message.text.startswith("@"))
async def handle_username_for_deletion(message: types.Message):
    if is_user_allowed(message.from_user.id):
        await message.answer("Атака запущена!")
        # Случайное время ожидания между 1 и 20 минутами
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 20) * 60)
        await message.answer("Готово, аккаунт снесён!")
    else:
        await message.answer("Извините, у вас нет доступа к этому действию.")

# Запуск бота
async def main():
    init_db()
    await dp.start_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())


Приведите [mcve] и полный текст ошибки, копаться в такой оогромной портянке кода без контекста никто не будет

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "m:\тг\emptysnoser.py", line 21, in 
dp = Dispatcher(bot)  # Передаем бот в диспетчер
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Dispatcher.init() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Ну, если открыть документацию, то там видно, что Dispatcher не принимает никаких позиционных аргументов, из чего следует, что «Передаем бот в диспетчер» это чушь

а как можно это пофиксить ?

Ну, переписать код в соответствии с документацией aiogram, наверное?

все,понял спасибо
